# Linker warning causes random linking errors every few compilations

Tags: c++, opengl, linker, glfw, glew

I can't get a minimal reproduceable example any smaller than what I have. Mainly because I can't debug the issue, it seems completely random and I don't consistently get the error, sometimes it compiles, sometimes it doesn't. I have reverted back to when I had the error so I can copy the code, but since then, I haven't gotten an error. Basically, I have no other ideas left other than to fix all my linker warnings. I remember it was mostly related to this warning `LNK4042 object specified more than once; extras ignored` **in main.obj**. There is also another warning I don't understand, that being I have the binaries for a library named `GLEW`, yet statically linking it invokes a linker warning, `LNK4099 PDB 'vc120.pdb' was not found with 'glew32s.lib(glew.obj)' or at '\SolutionDir\Debug\vc120.pdb'; linking object as if no debug info`

What are the fixes for these warnings? Hopefully to stop me randomly getting errors that, when I change one thing it compiles, and then revert it back and it still compiles.

Here is the code, **main.h**

```
#pragma once

#ifndef MAIN_H
#define MAIN_H


#include <GL/glew.h>  // Initialize with glewInit()

#ifndef GLFW_INCLUDE_NONE
#define GLFW_INCLUDE_NONE // GLFW including OpenGL headers causes ambiguity or multiple definition errors.
#endif // GLFW_INCLUDE_NONE

       
#include <GLFW/glfw3.h>


#include "ImGui/imgui.h"
#include "ImGui/implot.h"
#include "ImGui/imgui_impl_glfw.h"
#include "ImGui/imgui_impl_opengl3.h"


#include <iostream> //std::string

 

class Main    ///Singleton
{
public:
    Main(const Main&) = delete;
    Main(Main&&) = delete;
    Main& operator=(const Main&) = delete;
    Main& operator=(Main&&) = delete;



private:
    Main();


    static Main& Get_Instance();



    friend int main(int argc, char* argv[]);


    static void Mainloop();
    static void Init();
    static void Free();



    GLFWwindow* m_Window = nullptr;


    std::string m_GLSL_Version = "";

    int m_Window_Width = 1280;
    int m_Window_Height = 720;


};




#endif // MAIN_H
```

and **main.cpp**

```
#include "main.h"



Main::Main()
{

}



Main& Main::Get_Instance()
{
    static Main instance;
    return instance;
}




void Main::Init()
{

    // Setup window
    Get_Instance(); //Init constructor


    if (!glfwInit()) {
        std::cout << "Could not initialize GLFW" << std::endl;
        std::cin.get();
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }


    Get_Instance().m_GLSL_Version = "#version 460";
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MAJOR, 4);
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MINOR, 6);


    // Create window with graphics context
    Get_Instance().m_Window = glfwCreateWindow(Get_Instance().m_Window_Width, Get_Instance().m_Window_Height, "Program", NULL, NULL);
    if (Get_Instance().m_Window == NULL) {
        std::cout << "Could not create GLFW window" << std::endl;
        std::cin.get();
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }


    glfwMakeContextCurrent(Get_Instance().m_Window);


    glfwSwapInterval(0); //  vsync
     


    if (glewInit() != GLEW_OK)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Failed to initialize OpenGL loader!\n");
        std::cin.get();
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    // Setup Dear ImGui context
    IMGUI_CHECKVERSION();
    ImGui::CreateContext();
    ImPlot::CreateContext();

    // Setup Dear ImGui style 
    ImGui::StyleColorsClassic();

    // Setup Platform/Renderer backends
    ImGui_ImplGlfw_InitForOpenGL(Get_Instance().m_Window, true);
    ImGui_ImplOpenGL3_Init(Get_Instance().m_GLSL_Version.c_str());

}




void Main::Mainloop()
{


    // Main loop
    while (!glfwWindowShouldClose(Get_Instance().m_Window))
    {


        //Events
        glfwPollEvents();


        // Start the Dear ImGui frame
        ImGui_ImplOpenGL3_NewFrame();
        ImGui_ImplGlfw_NewFrame();
        ImGui::NewFrame();



        ImGui::Text("%.3f", ImGui::GetIO().Framerate);



        // Rendering
        ImGui::Render();
        glfwGetFramebufferSize(Get_Instance().m_Window, &Get_Instance().m_Window_Width, &Get_Instance().m_Window_Height);
        glViewport(0, 0, Get_Instance().m_Window_Width, Get_Instance().m_Window_Height);
        glClearColor(0.45f, 0.55f, 0.60f, 1.00f);
        glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
        ImGui_ImplOpenGL3_RenderDrawData(ImGui::GetDrawData());

        glfwSwapBuffers(Get_Instance().m_Window);
    }

  

}





void Main::Free()
{

    // Cleanup
    ImGui_ImplOpenGL3_Shutdown();
    ImGui_ImplGlfw_Shutdown();
    ImPlot::DestroyContext();
    ImGui::DestroyContext();


    glfwDestroyWindow(Get_Instance().m_Window);
    glfwTerminate();
}
  





int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{

    Main::Init();
    Main::Mainloop();
    Main::Free();


    return 0;
}
```

Edit: It happened again, here are the errors:

```
Error   LNK1561 entry point must be defined
Warning LNK4042 object specified more than once; extras ignored (THIS IS IN MY main.obj file, its the only linker issue that references my actual files, the rest reference either 'LINK' or 'libucrt.lib(something here)'
Error   LNK2005 __cexit already defined in ucrtd.lib(ucrtbased.dll) 
Error   LNK2005 __crt_atexit already defined in ucrtd.lib(ucrtbased.dll)    
Error   LNK2005 __crt_at_quick_exit already defined in ucrtd.lib(ucrtbased.dll) 
Error   LNK2005 __execute_onexit_table already defined in ucrtd.lib(ucrtbased.dll)
Error   LNK2005 __initialize_narrow_environment already defined in ucrtd.lib(ucrtbased.dll) 
Error   LNK2005 __initialize_onexit_table already defined in ucrtd.lib(ucrtbased.dll)
Error   LNK2005 __register_onexit_function already defined in ucrtd.lib(ucrtbased.dll)
Error   LNK2005 __seh_filter_dll already defined in ucrtd.lib(ucrtbased.dll)
```

Comment: If you expect a nice way to get a vector from C++, there isn't one, the ODBC C++ API is very low-level. If you want a high-level API, use a toolkit or framework like Qt or .Net framework.

Comment: If you're using Visual Studio, I'd advise using C++/CLI with .Net, there are many great tutorials out there, and with .Net 5/.Net core it can be crossplatform. You can then use OdbcDataReader to read from a managed ODBC connection.

Comment: Show the exact settings you use for compilation, show the exact error messages.

Comment: @BDL I got it to give me the errors again. I edited the question. Just additionally, when I clean the solution and rebuild, the errors disappear, but it takes a while to do this so optimally I want to get rid of it

Comment: Random occuring Errors are hard to track down. First i would make sure, that you have enough free memory and diskspace during linking. This can lead to all kinds of weird behaviour. Second: Please rename your Main class. Third: Why is you main class a singleton? Its not necessary. Incorporate those changes and see if your linker error persists

Comment: And why is the main function a friend of your Main Class? Remove that.

Comment: @Taron So when I (or anyone else) accidently includes `main.h` they can't call any of its functions. Why would I remove that? `main` or `Main` is a different thing. Ill rename it and see, but I can't see a functional reason other than that why I should remove or make it not a singleton. It has many benefits, being It can't be constructed, and it can only be used correctly, it can't be used for any reason it wasn't meant for. Also I have plenty of memory and disk space.

Comment: I haven't gotten any errors again, but its only been about 10 mins or so after quite a few re compiles, all the warnings are still there. Its quite hard to know if that fixed it or not since they are really random.

Comment: @wiourow seoif. I strongly recommend that you read about proper class design, oop, interfaces and decoupling of classes and components. Why would anyone ever accidently include main.h and then accidently use an instance of main? Now you coupled your Main class very tight to the main function. In fact so tight that noone else can use it. Singletons are very often (almost always) a code smell, because they tend to break encapsulation unbeknownst to clients. Give your main class a proper public interface, use the CTOR. Instantiate it in your main function and use the public funtions.

Comment: What reason would I need to do this if it is just responsible for handling the `mainloop` of the program. There should only be ONE `mainloop` and since this class handles the `mainloop` I need a way to make sure it is only called once. This way it is impossible for any person working on the project who didn't make the file `main.h` to do anything they shouldn't be doing. I dont understand what is wrong with this?

Comment: It seems like the same argument of `smart pointers`, why they have their assignment operator destroyed, its to stop people from digging themselves into a hole, to me it seems like that same principle is applying here?

Comment: You're having build issues so you need to post info about how you're building the source. Is this a Visual Studio project with a `.vcxproj` or a `Makefile` project or what? How much have you changed the settings from the defaults? In general, stick with the defaults as much as possible and only change settings if you specifically need to.

Comment: @gavinb yeah, vs with .vcxproj and default settings

Comment: How are you linking against GLFW and GLEW? How are the dependencies provided?

Comment: static linking, the provided binaries from their websites, 32bit.

Comment: The linker errors we see are do with the CRT. What CRT linkage settngs are you using? It could be that the GLEW libs you have refer to a different version of the CRT, so your project and GLEW are trying to link in two different (but same) libs. But you only ever get the error when you use a GLEW function that requires the CRT. Maybe.

Comment: I would try and help you but ImGui is not nice to have to try and install!

Comment: @AshleyMiller I dont even use any GLEW functions. I just have it so ImGui can initialize. I'm not quite sure what CRT settings means, I haven't modified my settings in the project after making a new C++/CLI project, just default and then includes and libs linked

Answer (score 0):

Regarding the LNK4042 warning, you may be able to resolve the issue, if you open the properties for the entire project, and the change the value under C/C++ -> Output Files -> "Object File Name" to be the following:

$(IntDir)/%(RelativeDir)/